# What is the best way to modify entry data when submitting and updating entries

Tags: matrix, hook, update

I am looking to modify a counter which is a field in a channel when i submit or update an entry. I am looking to count the number of matrix rows and then add that into the input field to act as the counter.

What is the best way for me to do this?

What hook should i use?

And what files should i create?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you can get this count in your template by using `{my_matrix_field:total_rows}` - but I'll assume you need the number stored as a value in a field for other purposes (use in `orderby` perhaps).

In which case - yes, you'd write an [extension](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html), and use the [entry_submission_ready](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/#entry-submission-ready) hook.

Then in your method, pass `$data` by reference, so you can modify it. Check to make sure you're in the channel you're looking for, then dump the `$data` array so you can see how the data is structured. From there you can figure out how to count your Matrix rows, and then set the value of `$data['field_id_XX']` (which would be your "counter" field).

```
function entry_submission_ready($meta, &$data, $autosave)
{
    if($meta['channel_id'] == XX)
    {
        // This is just to let you examine the data - you'd remove it after
        print_r($data);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your correct. It is to use as a counter for the search parameter. Where you have put the print_r statement is this where I would get the matrix row count and then add it to the field, in this example the field is field_id_6. Does this function run and show and output to test? And does it automatically run in the background when live?

Comment: Yeah, I can't recall off-hand what the Matrix field data will look like (hence the `print_r()` so you can examine it) - if you write and install an extension which uses the code on the hook mentioned, then yes, it will run automatically with each entry, and show you the output while you have the `print_r()` and `exit()`statements inside of it. (You'd want to remove them after you figure out your code.)